# Are houses masculine or feminine?

Tags: pronouns

Ships and boats are referred to using feminine pronouns.  Are houses masculine, feminine or neutral?  Please provide evidence for your answer, a Google search didn't help me.

Comment: Neutral, ie referred to as "it".  Boats are neutral too - it may be common to call a boat "she" but this is just a romantic tradition, not a feature of the language.

Comment: It's always safe to assume inanimate, mindless objects don't have gender in English. Calling ships "she" is a freak exception that isn't even required, just an optional bit of personification.

Comment: The use of gendered terms for inanimate objects has all but vanished. That said, when they were used, they were almost universally feminine. I'm not aware of any masculine parallels to the construction, e.g., "The sea was a harsh mistress that day, she was....".

Comment: @DanBron: Death is usually personified as male. I think Time is also, to a lesser degree. Of course, these are abstract concepts, rather than concrete inanimate objects.

Comment: @sumelic True, Mother Nature and Father Time, but I think that only really applies to the actual personifications, "time incarnate", unlike applying feminine pronouns to the literal sea itself.

Comment: Only your Feng Shui master can determine the gender of your house...

Comment: Relevant: [When referring to a noun, when does the gender matter?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118/when-referring-to-a-noun-when-does-the-gender-matter)

Comment: Related: [Pronoun question: referring to inanimate objects as 'he' or 'she'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287721/pronoun-question-referring-to-inanimate-objects-as-he-or-she) and [Is English “genderless” or are inanimate nouns just neuter by default?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234745/is-english-genderless-or-are-inanimate-nouns-just-neuter-by-default)

Comment: Also: [Referring to objects as “she”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3178/referring-to-objects-as-she) and [Is it a good practice to refer to countries, ships etc using the feminine form?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12632/is-it-a-good-practice-to-refer-to-countries-ships-etc-using-the-feminine-form)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I was just curious if houses are feminine because vehicles (like ships are).  That's all there was to it.

Comment: If you were Italian, I might have understood because "casa" is feminine, but the exception to the rule that inanimate objects are genderless are few and far between:  ships, boats, cars, and weather elements. See top answer  in  *Pronoun question: referring to inanimate objects as 'he' or  'she'* for a detailed list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the *Chicago Manual of Style* has to say:

**5.14 Noun gender**

English nouns have no true gender as that property is understood in many other languages. For example, whether a noun refers to a masculine or feminine person or thing does not determine the form of the article as it does in French, German, Spanish, and other languages. Still, some English words--almost exclusively denoting a person or an animal--are inherently masculine {uncle}{rooster}{lad} or feminine {aunt}{hen}{lass} and take the gender-appropriate pronouns. But by far, most English nouns are common in gender and may refer to either sex {relative}{chicken}{child}. Many words that once were considered strictly masculine--especially words associated with jobs or professions--have been accepted as common in gender over time {author}{executor}{proprietor}. Similarly, many forms made feminine by the addition of a suffix {aviatrix} have been abandoned

**House is gender neutral.**

Comment: *Chicago* has a most righteous discussion of avoiding gender bias in writing: 5.221-5.230. If you have access online, hardcover, or go to the library, I found this to be imperative for good gender-neutral prose.

Answer (score 0):

Houses have no special gender, they are neuter. Ships had often female names, that's why they are feminine. Houses fall under the general rule: Things are neuter.

I looked around on the Internet about Gender in English. Wikipedia is indigestible, other websites bring only half of the topic. I found no site that mentions ships, cars, country names like France, sun, moon, etc.

You have to look into a real grammar, chapter nouns, gender.

Added: from en.wikipedia - grammatical gender - 14.1.1 English:
They mention that countries, ships, and other vehicles are feminine. No mention of sun (he, analogue to Latin sol,solis m), and moon (she, analogue to Latin luna f) in poetry.

[Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender#English)

Comment: This is true, but it's better offered as a comment, not as an answer.  Unless you want to dig up the evidence OP asked for, which isn't a small task.

Comment: I wasn't finished with my post.

Comment: K, take your time then.

Comment: Often, when I'm writing a post and switch to the Internet and go back to my post, it has vanished. So I save what I have written and then try to find something on the Internet.

Comment: Well, that shouldn't happen. In fact, SE should save a (private) draft for you automatically, every Z seconds, which will be available for further editing and ultimately publishing from anywhere you log in. If you can reproduce this bug, it's very much worth your time to report it on [Meta.SE].

Comment: @rogermue Please provide evidence for your answer.  "I looked around on the Internet" doesn't help me, because that's exactly what I did, and I didn't find the information I was looking for.

Comment: You can find something in en.wikipedia, grammatical gender, point 14.1.1 English  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender

Comment: @rogermue Would you mind incorporating the relevant material from that source into your answer? Particularly after OP's comment above yours, I feel that my first comment in this thread still stands.